# How does the program know the size of this dynamic string

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls, c-strings

The following example of NASM assembly is meant to be called with a command-line argument representing a target filename to write in:

```sh
$ ./myprogram myfile.txt
```

On Linux systems, at the beginning of the program, the stack is filled with A. the count of arguments including the program name (here, 2) and B. the memory address at which each argument starts.

```nasm
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    pop ebx             ; argc (argument count) (not used)
    pop ebx             ; memory offset for the program name (not used)
    pop ebx             ; memory offset for the filename

    mov eax, 8          ; syscall to create a file (filename is read from ebx)
    mov ecx, 00644Q     ; read/write permissions in octal (rw_rw_rw_)
    int 80h             ; Call the kernel
```

Given that `filename.txt` is created dynamically from the input of the user, how does the file creator know the size of the filename? Assuming the offset of the first character is 500 (meaning `ebx = 500`), then the memory would look as follows (representing the `Char`s instead of their hex values):

```
498   499   500   501   502   503   504   505   506   507   508   509   510   511
 ?     ?     m     y     f     i     l     e     .     t     x     t     ?     ?
```

I don't see anywhere in the code that indicates that the file name stops at `509`. If the value in `ebx` is `500`, then how does the file creator know that it has to stop reading the filename at `509`?

Could it be that when command-line arguments are automatically pushed into the stack, each of them is terminated by a `null` character that the file creator is expecting?

Comment: Paths as args to Unix system calls are 0-terminated C strings, implicit-length.  Same as the elements of the argv array.

Comment: Yes, command line arguments (like all strings you deal with in the UNIX programming interface) are NUL terminated.